# phpmailer attachment is not working

Tags: email, phpmailer, attachment

I am trying to send an image attachment  using phpmailer. It is not working properly. Thank you in advance

Here is the code:

```
$mail->AltBody = $message;
$uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['file_attach']['name']));
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'My uploaded file');
}
```

When i echo $uploadfile, i got this C:\Users\DOER Lenovo\AppData\Local\Temp\da33CF.tmp

I think there is something error here move_uploaded_file.

Thanks

Comment: So check your return values, make sure that the file does actually exist.

Comment: I just found out, It is showing following errors
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: file_attach in <b>C:\xamppp\htdocs\212\heinz\send.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
<br />
<b>C:\xamppp\htdocs\212\heinz\send.php</b> on line <b>27</b><br />
<br />
<b>C:\xamppp\htdocs\212\heinz\send.php</b> on line <b>28</b><br />

<b>C:\xamppp\htdocs\212\heinz\send.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

For these codes 
$file_name = $_FILES['file_attach']['name'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['file_attach']['tmp_name'];

Comment: html code : <input type="file" name="file_attach" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*">

Comment: Did you include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag?

Comment: Yes, I did, 
 <form class="fields" id="contact-form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

And i am using ajax.

Comment: Ah, well if you're using ajax it may be a different story. Use your web inspector to look at the requests you make, perhaps try a `var_dump($_POST)` in your script to confirm what you're receiving.

Comment: I have recieved value from all other field except file type. It is showing undefined index. And showing null while tried to check using var_dump

Comment: OK, so you need to check your JS code.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah, it was problem in my js code.